# AJAX Request on PhoneGap Server

Tags: python, html, ajax, apk, phonegap

I'm trying to get AJAX to work on my PhoneGap app. When using the PhoneGap Desktop server, the AJAX request reaches the PythonAnywhere server, as evidenced by the Access Log.

However, when converting it to an APK, the server does not receive a request (not seen in the access log).

HTML: https://pastebin.com/xG5MCf75

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Blank App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"/>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function testAjax(){
                alert('button pressed')
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    headers:{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'},
                    url: "http://18choym.pythonanywhere.com/testAJAX",
                    data: {
                        someData: 'hi'
                    },
                    success: function(results){
                        alert('f1')
                        // console.log(results["data"])
                        // alert(results["data"])
                        alert('f2')
                        // acessing post data as 'result' returns an obj error.
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                        alert('Error Message: '+error)
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <button onclick='testAjax();'>V3</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Python: https://pastebin.com/9G6Wdqqi